# Docker portability issues with locally saved images

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am currently working on a project that requires an airtight cloud infrastructure. Thus all artefacts, including docker images, have to be available offline.

It appears that the `docker save` and the subsequent `docker import` do not result in an equal Docker image.

Docker version: 1.10.3

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED            SIZE

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker pull registry:2
2: Pulling from library/registry
fdd5d7827f33: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
a79b4a92697e: Pull complete 
6cbb75c7cc30: Pull complete 
4831699594bc: Pull complete 
Digest:    sha256:20f5d95004b71fe14dbe7468eff33f18ee7fa52502423c5d107d4fb0abb05c1d
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry:2

$ docker run -p 5000:5000 -v /data/docker_images:/tmp/registry-dev registry:2 
time="2016-04-01T19:11:55Z" level=warning msg="No HTTP secret provided - generated random secret. This may cause problems with uploads if multiple registries are behind a load-balancer. To provide a shared secret, fill in http.secret in the configuration file or set the REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET environment variable." go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=af87e7b7-9b56-49a6-bf71-4bd04e141c95 version=v2.3.1 
time="2016-04-01T19:11:55Z" level=info msg="redis not configured" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=af87e7b7-9b56-49a6-bf71-4bd04e141c95 version=v2.3.1 
time="2016-04-01T19:11:55Z" level=info msg="using inmemory blob descriptor cache" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=af87e7b7-9b56-49a6-bf71-4bd04e141c95 version=v2.3.1 
time="2016-04-01T19:11:55Z" level=info msg="listening on [::]:5000" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=af87e7b7-9b56-49a6-bf71-4bd04e141c95 version=v2.3.1 
time="2016-04-01T19:11:55Z" level=info msg="Starting upload purge in 45m0s" go.version=go1.5.3 instance.id=af87e7b7-9b56-49a6-bf71-4bd04e141c95 version=v2.3.1
```

The above run successfully!

My aim is to save the Docker Registry image as a ***.tar** file, move it to another server, import the image there and will be able to run the Docker Registry as I could when it was pulled from Internet/ Docker Hub. Below is the sequence of commands, all run one the same machine, that led to the error.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry            2                   83139345d017        3 weeks ago         165.8 MB

$ docker save 83139345d017 > registry.tar

$ docker import registry.tar foo/registry
sha256:8e84e7d07f97825b0ebaa04054f988566bb7b90083ba80caec6398e085adce84

$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
foo/registry        latest              8e84e7d07f97        3 seconds ago       172.3 MB
registry            2                   83139345d017        3 weeks ago         165.8 MB

$ docker run -p 5000:5000 -v /data/tmp:/tmp/registry-dev foo/registry
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Error... It somehow expects a command, whereas when pulled directly from the Docker Hub, it doesn't require a command. Also note that the image sizes are a couple of MBs different.

Is this a bug or do I miss something here?

Comment: It is worth noting that the opposite of `docker save` is `docker load`, not `docker import`. Compare [docker-load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) docs with [docker-import](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) docs.

Comment: @larsks Thank you, your answer saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

@larsks comment resolved it. The problem was that I use the wrong function to import the image. The correct function to use is `docker load`!

Below is a sequence of commands that are suitable for creating, moving and loading Docker images.

Assumptions:

- Local Docker registry runs on IP `10.10.10.10:5000`
- Docker image from Docker Hub is called `stack/overflow` (This image does not exist! The image name is used for illustration only.)

Here we go...

```
# Pull the image from public Docker Hub
$ docker pull stack/overflow:0.9

# List the images
$ docker images
stack/overflow              0.9              57cbfaed16bf        7 months ago        20.96 MB

# Change the name of the image to match your local Docker Registry address
$ docker tag 57cbfaed16bf 10.10.10.10:5000/overflow:0.9

# Save Docker image
# IMPORTANT: You need to use the "repo/tag" to select the image to be saved, as it otherwise does not save the "repo/tag" information in the tar file!
$ docker save -o overflow.tar 10.10.10.10:5000/overflow:0.9

# Copy the overflow.tar file to the offline environment, which as the Docker Registry running on 10.10.10.10:5000

# Load Docker image
$ docker load -i overflow.tar

# List the images
$ docker images
10.10.10.10:5000/overflow              0.9              38ea67f2e6d8        7 months ago        20.96 MB

# Push the image to the local registry
$ docker push 10.10.10.10:5000/overflow
```